# [php] Работа с куки  на локальном хосте

Tags: php, cookie

Установлен сервер Денвер.
Вся работа не в корне, а в подпапке /admin/../../

Как установить куки ко всему домену и всем подпапкам внутри. УСтановка куки через login.php и продления их через auth.inc.php из любой папки и подпапки, а также их отключить/стереть из любой подпапки.

Установка куки в файле http://localhost/admin/login.php (по умолчанию может быть где угодно)

```
//Login.php

$sessionTime = 3600;
setcookie("id",   $loginData['id'], time()+$sessionTime); 
setcookie("hash", $hash,            time()+$sessionTime);

//Auth.inc.php (Из любой папки)

$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
$sessionTime = 3600;
setcookie('id',   $uData['id'],     time()+$sessionTime, $domain, false);
setcookie('hash', $hash,            time()+$sessionTime, $domain, false);

// Quit.inc.php

$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;

setcookie('id',   "", time()-60*60*24*365, "/", $domen, false);
setcookie('hash', "", time()-60*60*24*365, "/", $domen, false);

if(session_id() !== '' or isset($_SESSION))  session_destroy();
header('Location: /admin/login.php?redirect=true');
```

Login.php и auth.inc.php работают, но с горе паполам, а quit.inc.php вообще отказался стирать куки

Да я в курсе, что нужно указывать домен, папку и минусовое время,но нихрена не работает или работает через заднее место. Прошу помоши!

Comment: Решил зделать так: Если присутствует ?quit редиректим на логин.php а там уже убиваем куки. Код весь размазан на несколько файлов поэтому трудно его показать. Так можно делать вообще ???

Comment: @jcmax

> Код весь размазан на несколько файлов поэтому трудно его показать. Так можно делать вообще ???

Нет.  
По-хорошему делается так: создается какой-нибудь файл типа `CookieSuite.php`, в котором объявляется класс/функции для рабоыт с куками. После этого он подключается везде, где нужен, и тянутся уже функции типа `setDomainCookie($name, $value, $expire)`, `removeCookie($name)`. После этого таким же отдельным файлом добавляется авторизация, которая работает **на основе** кук. У нее тоже есть какие-нибудь функции `auth()` и `logout()`, которые уже подтягиваются в нужных местах.

Comment: Совсем по-хорошему конечно фреймворк использовать.

Comment: т.е. это работает только на реальном сервере? Потому, что в моем случае, если я даже все закину в cookie.inc.php и туда установку кук и очистку кук. там же пути у всех папок разные и куки которые в /folder1 и /folder1/folder2 могут быть разные. У меня проблема в том, что куки которые устанавливаются в /admin/login.php не стираются в /admin/inc/auth.inc.php?quit=clear_cookie

Comment: jcmax, браузер не делает разницы между локалхостом и сервером "где-то там", равно как и апач в денвере. Такое, что в одном месте работает, в другом нет - бывает, но в 99% случаев из-за неверно написанного кода. Кука, установленная для всего домена (path='/') должна быть видна всему домену вне зависимости от папки.  
Куки, по большому счету - просто еще один заголовок в общении сервер-клиент, вы можете сами посмотреть в заголовках (в панели разработчика в хроме, например), что кому отсылается и что приходит.

Comment: ок! понятно теперь проверил без кода все нормально